# dynamic database

Tags: codeigniter

In the config.php file of Codeigniter are static variables. I want to transform as a dynamic variable. I got the variable session and then want to replace into that static variable.
how can I do? please give any examples.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[From Codeigniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html):

> If you would like to dynamically set a config item or change an existing one, you can so using:

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

> Where item_name is the $config array index you want to change, and item_value is its value.